# A script to strip ranges of UTF-8 Characters out of a file

Tags: python, perl, unicode, utf-8

My problem is that I have a data file containing UTF-8, most of which is valid and must be kept, but some of which has random "garbage" UTF-8, namely in the range of `0xf0 - 0xff`. An example of the hex for the bad data can be seen below

```
 f4 80 80  ab f4 80 80 b6 f4 80 80 
 a5 f4 80 80 a6 f4 80 80  83 f4 80 80 b6 f4 80 81  
 84 f4 80 81 98 f4 80 81  87 f4 80 81 8c f4
```

I'm trying to write a perl script that will search and replace for characters that the first byte is in the range `0xf0 - 0xff`. On [this website](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl) the codepage is listed as private use.

My existing attempts either do nothing, or have only been able to remove the first byte of a multi-byte character, such as `perl -CSD -pi.orig -e 's/[\x{f4}-\x{ff}]/?/g'` Running perl v5.12.5

I'm not much of a perl expert, nor a utf-8 expert. I'm also open to doing this in ruby/python/C++(98)/whatever as long as it's relatively portable on a linux box.

Here's a link to a snippet of the garbage data. http://pastebin.com/LR0StPHu

Comment: Now my question is, how do I get demo data into my code? :D

Comment: @simbabque Pastbin for you http://pastebin.com/LR0StPHu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, let's not mix up a few things.

UTF-8 characters whose first byte is `0xf0` are four bytes long, which is the most you ever need to encode a legal Unicode character. Since over 94% of the possible Unicode range requires that fourth byte, `0xf0` doesn't map to any single code page, and certainly not to the private use areas.

Such characters *are* outside the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane). But that's different from being invalid or private use; it just means their code points are greater than U+FFFF (decimal value 65,535).

If you want to exclude all characters outside the BMP, you should be searching for the ones matching this regex:

```
[\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]
```

That uses Perl's `\x{`...`}` interpolation syntax to include characters by their hexadecimal code point value. If you're actually using Perl, then for ease of use you might want to put the regex into a variable (using the quote-regex construction `qr(`...`)`, since bare slashes will immediately try to match the regex against `$_` at assignment time):

```
my $not_bmp = qr([\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]);
```

But, again, removing characters matching that regex eliminates over 94% of possible Unicode characters, so be sure that's what you want.

If you really only want to eliminate private use characters - some of which are *inside* the BMP - just exclude those ranges specifically. With Perl or Python or any other UTF-8-aware language, you don't have to worry about bytes; just check the code points.

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas#Unicode_PUA_blocks) will tell you, the three Private Use Areas are in these code point ranges:

- U+E000..U+F8FF
- U+F0000..U+FFFFF
- U+100000..U+10FFFF

So the corresponding Perl regex looks like this:

```
my $pua = qr([\x{e000}-\x{f8ff}\x{f0000}-\x{fffff}\x{100000}-\x{10ffff}]);
```

Many other languages have similar Unicode support (matching against UTF-8 characters, including characters in a string by code point, and so on). For example, here's Ruby, which mainly differs in using `\u{...}` instead of `\x{...}` for the interpolation:

```
not_bmp = %r([\u{10000}-\u{10FFFF}])
pua = %r([\u{e000}-\u{f8ff}\u{f0000}-\u{fffff}\u{100000}-\u{10ffff}])
```

Python `\u` escapes only work with exactly four hex digits, but if you have Python3 - or a Python2 compiled in *wide* mode - you can use capital `\U`, which takes exactly eight (there's no variable-length support via `{`...`}` as Perl and Ruby have):

```
not_bmp = re.compile(u'[\U00010000-\U0010ffff]')
pua = re.compile(u'[\ue000-\uf8ff\U000f0000-\U000fffff\U00100000-\U0010ffff]')
```

Comment: I've done some research on the BMP, and it appears to be exactly what I care about for the data we receive. Any data outside of this, incorrect or otherwise, is data that we don't want to be storing.

Comment: To give a bit of context, we're running into data issues when sending this data from a file to SQL Server, because SQL server does a conversion to UTF-16 for all Unicode data, and our particular driver has some fatal errors when it can't make the encoding switch properly. This data goes from UTF-16 Windows machines -> UTF-8 files -> UTF-16 SQL Server -> UTf-16 files -> UTF-8 files -> UTF-16 SQL Server. It's a damn mess. Thanks for correcting my poor understanding of UTF, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Sounds like something along the way doesn't really support UTF-16, but only UCS-2. Anyway, glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to work with characters, not with bytes.

If you have your data inside of your code, and you use the `use utf8` pragma to tell Perl that your program's source code is in utf8. We do this for the example so you can copy/paste my code.

You can do a string replace using the [`\x{}` escape sequence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Escape-sequences) in a character class `[]`. Those can be used in ranges as well as individually.

```
use utf8;

my $foo = "asfd ☃  Բարեւ ສະບາຍດີ";
$foo =~ s/[\x{10002b}\x{100036}]//g;
CORE::say $foo;
```

This will output:

```
asfd ☃  Բարեւ ສະບາຍດີ
```

(There's also a *wide character in print* warning, but let's ignore that, it's because my STDOUT is not opened properly).

The two characters I substituted `\x{10002b}\x{100036}` are the first two characters in your example data. The font I use in my IDE shows the ordinals of characters that it doesn't have any glyphs for, so it's easy for me to tell what those characters are.

[image: my font shows character ordinals]

These characters are from the [Supplementary Private Use Area-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas). ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block))

> 16 PUA-B  U+100000..U+10FFFF  Supplementary Private Use Area-B    65,536  65,534  Unknown

So we can also do a range.

```
my $foo = "asfd ☃  Բարեւ ສະບາຍດີ";
$foo =~ s/[\x{100000}-\x{10ffff}]//g;
CORE::say $foo;
```

Output:

```
asfd ☃  Բարեւ ສະບາຍດີ
```

To get all Private Use Areas, you need to include the three ranges which are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas#Assignment).

```
/[\x{E000}-\x{F8FF}\x{F0_000}-\x{FF_FFD}\x{100_000}-\x{10f_fff}]//g;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a waste of your time to have to look up the hex ranges of Private Use areas.  Simply say

s/\p{Private_Use}//g

perluniprops is the pod file that gives all the Unicode properties.  If you want just the above-BMP private use areas, you can consult it (grepping for Private) to find how to match those.